# I am having a problem with nodemon and socket.io in javascript

Tags: javascript, server, socket.io, nodemon

> I was trying to use the socket.io with nodemon. I created a server file which only contains this following code->

```
const io = require('socket.io')
```

> Then, when I runned the nodemon, that just showed this->

```
Debugger attached.
[nodemon] 2.0.16
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json  
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:464
    throw e;
    ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/permessage-deflate' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\Tanbir\Documents\Codings\Javascript\chat\node_modules\ws\package.json imported from C:\Users\Tanbir\Documents\Codings\Javascript\chat\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:440:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:692:3)
    at trySelf (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:458:34)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:910:24)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tanbir\Documents\Codings\Javascript\chat\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:14:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Seems like an error with the dependencies. Can you try deleting your `node_modules` folder, next re-install the dependencies again via `npm install` and then try again?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have opened the door to learning more!

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. Can you upvote my comment if it solved your issue?